# Golden Mean - Prove, in general, that For all $\in N | τ^{n+1} = τ^n + τ^{n-1} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Prove in general that For all $\in N | τ^{n+1} = τ^n + τ^{n-1}  $

I've been trying to work on this problem over the past few days and I seem to be missing something. I know that $ τ = (1 + √5)/2$

I also know τ is a root of $p(x) = x^2 - x -1 $

However even with this information I can't seem to figure it out. How would I prove this?

So far this is what I have

$0=t^2 + t^{n-1}  + t^{n+1} \rightarrow 0 = t^n(1 + t^{-1} + t) \rightarrow$
$ 0 = t^n(1 + \frac{1}{t} + t)  \rightarrow 0 = t^n(\frac{t + 1 + t^2}{t})$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\tau^{n+1}=\tau^{n-1}\tau^2=\tau^{n-1}(\tau+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide each term in your equation by $\tau^n$ and you'll get
$$\tau = 1+\frac{1}{\tau}.$$
Multiply both sides with $\tau$:
$$\tau^2 = \tau+1.$$
If you solve this easy quadratic equation, you will see that $$\tau_1=\varphi:=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2},\,\tau_2=\Phi:=\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}.$$